# What about performance of 1 to 1 or 0 when join to single view

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables, first table is a raw data for calculate result and store to second table (`tbl_cdn`) and some time in in calculation process may use some record of `tbl_fbk` like self join. My question is should I use 2 tables in 1 to 1 or 0 relation or merge into single table ?

**tbl_fbk**

- fbkrec_id
- name
- value_a
- value_b
- reference_result_value ( foriegn key to fbkrec_id on tbl_cdn)

**tbl_cdn**

- fbkrec_id
- result value

Comment: Start every project with as much normalized schema as it's possible. Denormalize **ONLY** if it's strongly required according to objective performance metrics

Comment: In addition to zerkms, if performance is your priority you should first generate a representative sample of data, fill your candidate structures and run tests using queries for data that your high-level logic demand.